# Regex to match name1.name2[.name3]

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate user id's matching the example:

```
smith.jack or smith.jack.s
```

In other words, any number of non-whitespace characters (except dot), followed by exactly one dot, followed by any number of non-whitespace characters (except dot), optionally followed by exactly one dot followed by any number of non-whitespace characters (except dot).  I have come up with several variations that work fine except for allowing consecutive dots!  For example, the following Regex

```
^([\S][^.]*[.]{1}[\S][^.]*|[\S][^.]*[.]{1}[\S][^.]*[.]{1}[\S][^.]*)$
```

matches "smith.jack" and "smith.jack.s" but also matches "smith..jack" "smith..jack.s" !  My gosh, it even likes a dot as a first character.  It seems like it would be so simple to code, but it isn't.  I am using .NET, btw.

Frustrating.

Comment: Do you *really* want to allow all non-whitespace characters? Would %{\\\=`.&^^@ be valid?

Comment: Actually, yes.  I have two validators, one for allowed characters and the other for correct format.  I don't want both of them firing at the same time, generally.  This means: no overlap.  I let the "ValidChar" validator handle things like "*&^%", and this one will make sure they are a.b or a.b.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^([^.\s]+)\.([^.\s]+)(?:\.([^.\s]+))?$

Comment: Longer than Guvante's earlier answer above, but still works fine!

Comment: As a bonus, it captures groups well, too.

Answer (score 6):

that helps?

```
/^[^\s\.]+(?:\.[^\s\.]+)*$/
```

or, in extended format, with comments (ruby-style)

```
/
  ^           # start of line
  [^\s\.]+    # one or more non-space non-dot
  (?:         # non-capturing group
    \.        # dot something
    [^\s\.]+  # one or more non-space non-dot
  )*          # zero or more times
  $           # end of line
/x
```

you're not clear on how many times you can have dot-something, but you can replace the `*` with `{1,3}` or something, to specify how many repetitions are allowed.

i should probably make it clear that the slashes are the literal regex delimiter in ruby (and perl and js, etc).

Comment: Your regex didn't work; Guvante's did -- and may the bird of paradise fly up your nose, too.  What kind of "more description title" would you have preferred?  Something like "Regex to validate any non-zero number of non-whitespace non-dot characters, followed by a dot, etc"?  Please enlighten me.

Comment: Yes, that would be a good title. Or "Regex to validate name pattern". Something at least a little less generic.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the * duplication, which allows for 0 iterations of the given component.

You should be using plus, and putting the final .[^.]+ into a group followed by ? to represent the possibility of an extra set.

Might not have the perfect syntax, but something similar to the following should work.

^[^.\s]+[.][^.\s]+([.][^.\s]+)?$

Or in simple terms, any non-zero number of non-whitespace non-dot characters, followed by a dot, followed by any non-zero number of non-whitespace non-dot characters, optionally followed by a dot, followed by any non-zero number of non-whitespace non-dot characters.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!  Now to try to parse it using wetware to see how to understand and learn from it.

Comment: This one seems to fail when the third group is more than one character, e.g. jack.smith.blah

Comment: In my application it is happy with jack.smith.blah

Comment: This is because the author changed it after I made my comment.

http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/87953/list

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with .NET's regexes. This will do what you want in Perl.

```
/^\w+\.\w+(?:\.\w+)?$/
```

If .NET doesn't support the non-capturing `(?:xxx)` syntax, use this instead:

```
/^\w+\.\w+(\.\w+)?$/
```

Note: I'm assuming that when you say "non-whitespace, non-dot" you really mean "word characters."

Comment: This doesn't match, for example: descartes.rené

Comment: What \w matches depends on your locale setting. It does in Perl, anyway, and should do so in .NET as well.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this has already been solved, but I find [Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) extremely helpful for prototyping regex's. The site has a load of simple explanations of the basics and lets you see what matches as you adjust the expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
[^\s.]+\.[^\s.]+(\.[^\s.]+)?
```

BTW what you asked for allows "." and ".."

Comment: are you sniffing my keyboard? You missed a ?, btw

Comment: I'm assuming that "a.b." is invalid thus the missing ? is not needed

Comment: Yes, realized so by garrett's comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd benefit from using + which means "1 or more", instead of * meaning "any number including zero".

Answer (score 0):

```
(^.)+|(([^.]+)[.]([^.]+))+
```

But this would match x.y.z.a.b.c and from your description, I am not sure if this is sufficiently restrictive.

BTW: feel free to modify if I made a silly mistake (I haven't used .NET, but have done plently of regexs)

Answer (score 0):

```
[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+(\.([^\s.]+?)?
```

has unmatched paren. If corrected to

```
[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+(\.([^\s.]+?))?
```

is still too liberal.  Matches a.b. as well as a.b.c.d. and .a.b
If corrected to

```
[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+(\.([^\s.]+?)?)
```

doesn't match a.b

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^.\W]+)\.?([^.\W]+)\.?([^.\W]+)$
```

This should capture as described, group the parts of the id and stop duplicate periods

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach.  I figured you really just wanted a string of non-space characters followed by only one dot, but that dot is optional (for the last entry).  Then you wanted this repeated.

```
^([^\s\.]+\.?)+$
```

Right now, this means you have to have at least one string of characters, e.g. 'smith' to match.  You, of course could limit it to only allow one to three repetitions with

```
^([^\s\.]+\.?){1,3}$
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) Is a good (non-free) tool for regex stuff